# Having Issues with my code comparing two binary trees with different structures

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare series of two binary trees and seeing if they have the same elements in them but the trees can have different structures all recursively.

Here is my current code, the "Find" function is a search the tree function:

```
private static boolean problem1Recursive(Node t1, Node t2)
    {
        if(t1 == null || t2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(find(t2, t1.key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return (problem1Recursive(t1.left, t2) && problem1Recursive(t1.right, t2));
    }
```

I'm just at a loss on where to go from here

Comment: By "different structure", you mean the trees could have the same values, but in different locations? For example, both trees might have the value 123, but in the first tree, the path is HLLLRRL, and in the other tree it is at HLRRL ?  ("H" refers to the root node, "L" means go to the left child, and "R" means go to the right child.)

Comment: The first answer begins with "The code you provided seems to be checking if all elements in the first tree exist in the second tree, rather than checking if the two trees have the same elements." If your code does that and is working, you could call that method twice:  `boolean haveSameContents  = problem1Recursive (treeA.root, treeB.root) && problem1Recursive (treeB.root, treeA.root);`

Comment: If duplicate values are not allowed in your tree, you could copy the elements of one tree into a Set, the elements of another tree into another Set. Then, you can use the .equals method using your `Set` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be checking if all elements in the first tree exist in the second tree, rather than checking if the two trees have the same elements. But, in your problem statement you have stated that the trees can have different structures and you want to compare if they have the same elements.

Here is one possible solution to your problem:

```
private static boolean problem1Recursive(Node t1, Node t2) {
    if (t1 == null && t2 == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (t1.key != t2.key) {
        return false;
    }
    return problem1Recursive(t1.left, t2) || problem1Recursive(t1.right, t2);
}
```

This function first check if both nodes are null, if they are it returns true. If one of the nodes is null it returns false, indicating that the trees have different elements. If the key of the nodes is different it also returns false. It then recursively checks the left and right subtrees of the first tree against the entire second tree. If at least one of the subtrees contains all the elements of the second tree, the function will return true.

It's important to note that this solution considers that there aren't repeating values on the tree and the values are comparable.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping, but unfortunately that did not work. I think having the search function is vital to the program actually working. Thank you again